# Attribute Routing In Asp.net Core Web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I try to start asp.net core web api routing attribute as default route but when I access routing with parameter, I could not get any response

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class WarehousesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public WarehousesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    //http://localhost:2394/api/Warehouses/Project/1 (Not working)
    [HttpGet("Project/{projectId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetWarehouseByProjectId([FromRoute] int projectId)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var warehouse = await _context.warehouses.Include(x => x.Projects).Where(y => y.Projects.FirstOrDefault().ProjectId == projectId).ToListAsync();

        if (warehouse == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(warehouse);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean not working?Do you add a breakpoint to check whether you get the projectId in action?

Comment: return url not found but I don't include {projectId} and access url http://localhost:2394/api/Warehouses/Project. It's ok

Comment: @vannak by default the id will be zero (0) , which according to your code, may return a null warehouse and cause a `NotFound()` result to be returned.

Comment: It works well when I try your code.Could you show your startup routing?Do you have problem in a new project?

Comment: I test this url with postman. return not found url. It meas routing attribute with parameter not invoke to method

Comment: I used app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()

Comment: if you are using .NET 6 use this `[HttpGet("[action]/{projectId}")]` and call your action name

Answer (score 2):

Try with this one .This works fine for me

```
[HttpGet("Project/{projectId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetWarehouseByProjectId([FromRoute] int projectId)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid state");
    }

    var warehouse =await _context.warehouses.FindAsync(projectId);
    
    if (warehouse == null)
    {
        return NotFound("not found");
    }

    return Ok(warehouse);
}
```